# How can I access an arrayList item from another class in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, arraylist

I created a recycler view and feed data to it from MyAdapter class, I wanted to get name in recyler view item when it's clicked, On a youtube video I learnt how to get index of item (when clicked). I created an araryList of containing all the names in MyAdapter class, so I can access them it in MainAcitivty class by making a function to return needed arrayList value using index

```
public fun getName(pos: Int) : String {
        return nameList[pos]
    }
```

Now when I tried to call this function on MainActivity class and it shows an error (Unresolved reference: getName)

```
var name = MyAdapter.getName(position)
```

I did some searching and couldn't find a solution for this,
Can someone help me with properly calling a function in another class (in Kotlin)
or a better way to do the same thing
and sorry I'm new to Kotlin, Thank you!

Comment: what is the error you got? if it is an outOfBounds error, then do a size check first.

Comment: Unresolved reference: getName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code getName function is not static So you must get the name like this :

```
var name = (recyclerView.adapter as MyAdapter).getName(position)
```

But another way and correct way is to use the callback :

```
class MyAdapter(val onItemClick: (item: ItemModel?) -> Unit): 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<YourViewHolder>{
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: YourViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.binding.btn.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClick.invoke(yourList[position])
            }
         }
     }
```

Then in your activity or fragment listen to the callback

```
MyAdapter(){ item ->
}
```